# aggregate function alias error

Tags: sql, oracle, function, alias, aggregate

I have the following SQL code:

```
SELECT  ACTIVITY_TYPE, COUNT(EVENT_ID) as etv, SUM(etv) as etva, AVG(etva)
FROM ACTIVITIES, "EVENTS"
WHERE ACTIVITIES.ACTIVITY_ID="EVENTS".ACTIVITY_ID
GROUP BY ACTIVITY_TYPE;
```

This is an attempt to answer this question:

> d)    A query that provides management information on take up of the
>   various types of activities on offer. For each type of activity, the
>   query should show the total number of individuals who took that type
>   of activity and the average number of individuals taking each type of
>   activity.

unfortunately i get the following error :

```
ORA-00904: "ETVA": invalid identifier
```

Any help would be great!

EDIT:

```
SELECT  ACTIVITY_TYPE, COUNT(EVENT_ID), AVG(COUNT(EVENT_ID))
FROM ACTIVITIES, "EVENTS"
WHERE ACTIVITIES.ACTIVITY_ID="EVENTS".ACTIVITY_ID
GROUP BY ACTIVITY_TYPE;
```

This is the new query i am now getting this error:

```
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

TABLE STRUCTURE:

```
CREATE TABLE "GROUPS" (
  GROUP_ID NUMBER( 4 ) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT GROUP_ID_PK  PRIMARY KEY ,
  GROUP_NAME VARCHAR2(35) NULL,
  GROUP_NUMBER_OF_MEMBERS NUMBER( 3 ) NOT NULL ,
  GROUP_LEADER_ID NUMBER( 4 ) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE MEMBERS (
  MEMBER_ID NUMBER( 4 ) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT MEMBER_ID_PK  PRIMARY KEY ,
  MEMBER_SURNAME VARCHAR2( 35 ) NOT NULL ,
  MEMBER_FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2( 35 ) NOT NULL ,
  MEMBER_DOB DATE NOT NULL ,
  MEMBER_GENDER VARCHAR2( 1 ) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT MEMBER_GENDER_CHECK CHECK ( MEMBER_GENDER IN ( 'M' , 'F' ) ),
  GROUP_ID NUMBER( 4 ) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT GROUP_ID_FK_MEMBER FOREIGN KEY (GROUP_ID) REFERENCES "GROUPS"(GROUP_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE CHALETS (
  CHALET_NO NUMBER( 4 ) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CHALET_ID_PK  PRIMARY KEY ,
  CHALET_NAME VARCHAR2( 35 ) NOT NULL,
  CHALET_CAPACITY NUMBER( 2 ) NOT NULL,
  CHALET_RATE NUMBER( 6 , 2 ) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE SUPERVISORS (
  SUPERVISOR_ID NUMBER ( 4 ) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT SUPERVISOR_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY ,
  SUPERVISOR_SURNAME  VARCHAR2( 35 ) NOT NULL , 
  SUPERVISOR_FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2( 35 ) NOT NULL ,
  SUPERVISOR_MOBILE_NUMBER VARCHAR2( 11 ) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE ACTIVITIES (
  ACTIVITY_ID NUMBER ( 4 ) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT ACTIVITY_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY , 
  ACTIVITY_TYPE VARCHAR ( 35 ) NOT NULL , 
  ACTIVITY_TITLE VARCHAR2( 35 ) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE BOOKINGS (
  BOOKING_ID NUMBER( 4 ) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT BOOKING_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY , 
  GROUP_ID NUMBER( 4 ) NOT NULL , 
  CHALET_ID NUMBER( 4 ) NOT NULL ,
  BOOKING_START_DATE DATE NOT NULL , 
  BOOKING_END_DATE DATE NOT NULL ,
  CONSTRAINT GROUP_ID_FK_BOOKING FOREIGN KEY (GROUP_ID) REFERENCES GROUPS(GROUP_ID) ,
  CONSTRAINT CHALET_ID_FK_BOOKING FOREIGN KEY (CHALET_ID) REFERENCES CHALETS(CHALET_NO)
);

CREATE TABLE "EVENTS" (
  EVENT_ID NUMBER ( 4 ) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT EVENT_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY , 
  MEMBER_ID NUMBER ( 4 ) NOT NULL , 
  SUPERVISOR_ID NUMBER ( 4 ) NOT NULL ,
  ACTIVITY_ID NUMBER ( 4 ) NOT NULL ,
  EVENT_COMMENTS VARCHAR2( 500 ) ,
  EVENT_DATE DATE NOT NULL , 
  EVENT_TIME_SLOT VARCHAR2( 2 ) NOT NULL ,
  CONSTRAINT MEMBER_ID_FK_EVENT FOREIGN KEY (MEMBER_ID) REFERENCES MEMBERS(MEMBER_ID) ,
  CONSTRAINT SUPERVISOR_ID_FK_EVENT FOREIGN KEY (SUPERVISOR_ID) REFERENCES SUPERVISORS(SUPERVISOR_ID) ,
  CONSTRAINT ACTIVITY_ID_FK_EVENT FOREIGN KEY (ACTIVITY_ID) REFERENCES ACTIVITIES(ACTIVITY_ID)
);


ALTER TABLE "GROUPS" ADD CONSTRAINT MEMBER_ID_FK_GROUP_LEADER FOREIGN KEY (GROUP_LEADER_ID) REFERENCES MEMBERS(MEMBER_ID);
```

Comment: Did you mean `AVG(etv)` instead of `AVG(etva)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  etv and etva in your query are not columns but aliases. You cannot select them.
To select them follow this and give meaningful aliases to your queries/columns:

```
SELECT ACTIVITY_TYPE, count_etv, sum_etva, AVG(sum_etva) avg_atva
  FROM
  (
   SELECT ACTIVITY_TYPE, count_etv, SUM(count_etv) as sum_etva
     FROM
   (
    SELECT ACTIVITY_TYPE, COUNT(EVENT_ID) as count_etv  
       --, SUM(etv) as etva, AVG(etva) -- NOT columns you cannot select them
     FROM ACTIVITIES, "EVENTS"
    WHERE ACTIVITIES.ACTIVITY_ID="EVENTS".ACTIVITY_ID
   GROUP BY ACTIVITY_TYPE
   )
   GROUP BY ACTIVITY_TYPE, count_etv
  )
 GROUP BY ACTIVITY_TYPE, count_etv, sum_etva
 /
```

Second query - cleaner, more readable...:

```
SELECT ACTIVITY_TYPE -- optional
      , total_events  -- optional
     , AVG(total_events) avg_events
  FROM
  (
   SELECT ACTIVITY_TYPE
        , COUNT(EVENT_ID) total_events
     FROM ACTIVITIES, "EVENTS"
    WHERE ACTIVITIES.ACTIVITY_ID="EVENTS".ACTIVITY_ID
    GROUP BY ACTIVITY_TYPE
   )
  GROUP BY ACTIVITY_TYPE, total_events
  /
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `AVG(etva)`.

You cannot use **alias** in the same `SELECT list` where it was defined.

The bigger problem is that you cannot use aggregation function  `AVG` over a value (`SUM()`).

Based on the task description you need `AVG(etv)` as it has been already pointed out above by **codingbiz**.

**CONTINUE**  After the new query was posted.

My understanding is that `EVENTS` will have records connecting members with activities they participate in.

If so, you will need to `JOIN` `EVENTS` with `sub-query` that calculates counts for members from `EVENTS` and with 'ACTIVITIES' to just get Activity Titles.

Comment: @David Passmore - Exactly the same answer: you cannot use aggregation function (`AVG`) over a value (`COUNT()`).

Comment: @PM_77-1 Ok, how would you suggest i go about this?

Comment: @David Passmore - posted additional guidelines into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from posted structure. Each Event is unique, in each Event participates only one Member. So you cannot count average number of Members per activity because is just sum of Events with particular activity. Only total number of participants is possible:

```
SELECT  ACTIVITY_TYPE, COUNT(EVENT_ID)
FROM ACTIVITIES, "EVENTS"
WHERE ACTIVITIES.ACTIVITY_ID="EVENTS".ACTIVITY_ID
GROUP BY ACTIVITY_TYPE;
```

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Not quite, one member can participate in more that one activity, and more than one member can participate in one activity. Event table is there to prevent a many to many relationship.

Comment: You said : "So you cannot count average number of Members per activity because is just sum of Events with particular activity" but if you sum'ed the COUNT's then AVG it would work, no?

Comment: Hmm. Assume that we have a result of my query (Activity1, 15),(Activity2, 4). How do you want calculate average per activity?